# Find valuation rings of the function field $k(x,y)/k(xy)$ which do not contain $k[x,y]$.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, valuation-theory, function-fields

Let k be any field, then how does one find valuation rings of the function field $k(x,y)/k(xy)$ which do not contain $k[x,y]$? I believe there are two.

If we consider a rational function field $k(x,y)/k(x)$, then the only valuation ring which doesn't contain $k[x,y]$ is $k(x)[z]_{(z)}$ where $z=1/y$.

Notice that $k(x,y)/k(xy)$ is also a rational function field because $k(xy,x)=k(x,y)$. So shouldn't there only be one such valuation ring (based on what is known about rational function fields)?

(EDIT 14Aug2014) ANSWER: The only two valuation rings of the field extension $k(x,y)/k(xy)$ that do not contain $k[x,y]$ are $k(xy)[x^{-1}]_{(x^{-1})}$ and $k(xy)[y^{-1}]_{(y^{-1})}$.

Comment: Based on what is known about rational function fields, there is only one that doesn't contain $k[xy,y]$.

Comment: @Hurkyl $k[xy,y] \neq k[x,y] $, so I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: The fact you are referring to by "what is known about rational function fields", when applied to your question, should have $xy$ in place of $x$. And yes, that makes those two rings different, rather than the same as you had presumed.

Comment: It would be great if you put your thoughts as a complete answer.